# how to have both page numbers and and next & previous buttons in custom pager in asp.net grid view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, pagination

What I want is a pagination structure of this type .

[image]

I am able to display the previous and next buttons using the code below and they are functional too.

```
    <PagerTemplate>

          <asp:LinkButton CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Prev" ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" Style="color: Black">
                <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/videos_page_arrow_previous.gif"/>
          </asp:LinkButton>

          [Records <%= gridviewVideos.PageIndex * gridviewVideos.PageSize%>-<%= gridviewVideos.PageIndex * gridviewVideos.PageSize + gridviewVideos.PageSize - 1%>]

          <asp:LinkButton CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Next" ID="LinkButton3" runat="server" Style="color: Black">
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/videos_page_arrow_next.gif"/>
          </asp:LinkButton>  

    </PagerTemplate>
```

But I am not sure how to achieve in getting the page numbers in between them. Each page of mine contains 5 rows, if I use a repeater control to do that, then how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For these kind of scenarios you should ideally wanna use `asp:ListView` coupled with `asp:DataPager`. But if you are persisting with a `asp:GridView` you should extend it to use `asp:DataPager`

I have been using Matt Berseth's [Using a DataPager with the GridView Control - Implementing IPageableItemContainer](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/04/using_a_datapager_with_the_gri.html). But the demo / download site is down. So you could download the same from [GridView with DataPager in ASP.NET 3.5](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/nipuntomar/DataPagerGridView08012008123240PM/DataPagerGridView.aspx) which I believe is more or less trhe same code.